# Why is ListView not displaying the correct elements?

Tags: android, xml, listview

My android activity workout view displays a nested list view. Each object of the parent list displays and Exercise Name and 2 buttons and a child listview. The first parent list element doesn't show a child, the second shows the child list of the first, and the third shows the seconds child. If you scroll violently up and down the first parent will show the 3rd child list.

It looks like this on start:
[image]

After Scrolling Violently it looks like this: [image]

My XML is in three files

`activity_workout_view.xml` is the first:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.franzene.workoutplanner.WorkoutView">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

id/listview used `activity_workout_view_listview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="Dele"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="Add"
    />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_below="@id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And WorkoutViewAdapterListView.java is the adapter for the parent list and contains the adapter for the child list :

```
public class WorkoutViewAdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

DatabaseHelper db;
private Context context;
// private String[] text = {"hi","d"};
private int testInt = 0;
List<WorkoutExercise> WE_TABLE;
MyThumbnaildapter thadapter = null;


public WorkoutViewAdapterListView(Context context, int i) {
    this.context = context;
    testInt = i;
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    WE_TABLE = db.getWorkoutExercise(i + "");

    db.closeDB();


}

public int getCount() {
    //Log.e("Test" , "COUNT: " + totalSetCount + " + " + WE_TABLE.size() );
    return WE_TABLE.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private int[] getLocation(int i) {
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    int temp[] = {-1, -1};

    int count = -1;
    for (int we = 0; we < WE_TABLE.size(); we++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < db.getSetCountByWEID(WE_TABLE.get(we).getID()) + 1; s++) {
            count++;

            if (count == i) {
                //Log.e("Test","WE: " + we+ " S: " + s + " For: " + i);
                temp[0] = we;
                temp[1] = s;
                db.closeDB();
                return temp;
            }

        }
    }
    db.closeDB();
    return temp;
}

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetTable> {
    ArrayList<SetTable> arr;
    private TextView text;

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<SetTable> arr) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, arr);
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;
        View view = convertView;
        // if (view == null) {
        Log.e("Test","VIEWPOSITION:" + position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_workout_view_gridview_set, null);
        Button delButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn2);
        delButton.setTag(position);
        tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string2);
        delButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Test","buttonclick:" + position);

                int id = (Integer) v.getTag();
                arr.remove(id);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        tv.setText(arr.get(position).getWeight() + "lbs " + arr.get(position).getReps() + "times ");
        Log.e("Test", "view text:" + tv.getText());
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE642E"));

        //}
        return view;
    }

}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv;
    View view = convertView;
    ListView NumberList;


    // if (view == null) {


    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //view.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable("#e74c3c");
    // LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)(R.id.layout);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_workout_view_listview, null);
    tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Button deleteBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

    ArrayList<SetTable> S_TABLE = db.getSets(WE_TABLE.get(position).getID() + "");
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
    listView.setAdapter(thadapter);


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = listView.getLayoutParams();

    int h = listView.getCount() * listView.getMeasuredHeight();
    layoutParams.height = h;
    listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    thadapter = new MyThumbnaildapter(context, R.layout.activity_workout_view_gridview_set, S_TABLE);

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < thadapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = thadapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (thadapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();


    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
    //Log.e("Test", "Location: " + location[0] + " , " + location[1] + " Number " + Obj);


    String Exercises = WE_TABLE.get(position).getExerciseName();

    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e74c3c"));
    //deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tv.setText(Exercises);


    db.closeDB();

    //}

    return view;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use ListView inside a ListView item.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html
This seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think that is a better idea then the nested listview. I will try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but a list within a list isn't very good design.  You're probably hitting a bunch of contention with recycled views when you scroll fast.  Remember, that each time you scroll, "getView" gets called to recycled views for that list.  Then, for each item, it would need to call getView of the second list and recycle all those views..

Furthermore, this will cause some issues with what has focus.  When you go to click a button in the second "nested" list... are you clicking the nest list button?  The list item of the second list?  Or the list item of the parent list?  I hope you can see where you'll run into some issues with that.

Might I suggest that you have it set up so that you set it up so that you click a list item that transitions to another activity which contains a single list view for each excercise you did?

That aside... I noticed you're not using correct design pattern for your get view.  You're inflating new layouts EACH TIME you call get view.  This is an incredible resource hog to do this... and I could imagine it would be horrible for a nested list view.  You should use a view holder and check if the view is null.  If it's null, then inflate your layouts and acquire other resources as needed.  Then if it's not null, you should pull a reference from a view holder.

Read this document on how to incorporate this design pattern.
https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html